# How to prevent enumerate to indent a long text?

Tags: indentation, enumerate

How could I prevent enumerate to indent a long text? I am using this style for my enumeration:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\Alph*)}, ref=\Alph*, leftmargin=*]
\item Item \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

How could I get the text after `Item` directly at the bottom of `C)`?

Comment: Enumeration/item lists are basically defined for doing such indentation, from a typographical point of view.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Any alternative?

Comment: How about the `wide` option, though you will have to do some extra configuration as it will indent the label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\Alph*)}, ref=\Alph*, leftmargin=0em,itemindent=1.8em,labelwidth=\itemindent,labelsep=0em,align=left]
\setcounter{enumi}{2}
\item Item \\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: the same result would be obtained with the sorter options: `[label=\textbf{\Alph*)}, ref=2\Alph*, wide=0em]`.